# Error when calling a getter from another From

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class, forms

I have two Froms (Form1, Form2) and I'm getting this Error when I try to call a public function of Form2 from the Form1 class.

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'getText1' and no extension method 'getText1' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users...\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 24  17  WindowsFormsApplication1.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form gen = new Form2();
        gen.ShowDialog();
        gen.getText1(); // I'm getting the error here !!!
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string Text1;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string getText1()
    {
        return Text1;
    }

    public void setText1(string txt)
    {
        Text1 = txt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.setText1(txt1.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compile-time type of `gen` is currently just `Form`. Change that and it should be fine:

```
Form2 gen = new Form2();
gen.ShowDialog();
gen.getText1();
```

Note that this has nothing to do with GUIs in particular - it's just normal C#. If you're just starting out with C#, I suggest that you learn it with console apps instead - there are far fewer oddities that way, and you can learn one thing at a time.

I'd recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions, use properties as appropriate, and dispose of forms too:

```
using (Form2 gen = new Form2())
{
    gen.ShowDialog();
    string text = gen.Text1;
}
```

(Even then, `Text1` isn't a very descriptive name...)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've declared `gen` as the base type `Form`, which doesn't have such a method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form gen = new Form2();
    gen.ShowDialog();
    gen.getText1(); // I'm getting the error here !!!
}
```

Instead, you need to explicitly define it as type `Form2`, or use `var` to let the compiler infer the type:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gen = new Form2();
    gen.ShowDialog();
    gen.getText1();  // works fine now
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Form2 gen = new Form2();         
gen.ShowDialog();         
gen.getText1();
```

Hope this help.